# In R, how can I populate two columns with the results of the CIr function based on inputs from two other columns?

Tags: r

Thanks for any help in advance. I have a dataset with correlation values in a column called 'exit' and corresponding sample sizes (n) in a column called 'samplesize' in a data frame called 'dataset'.

My task is to create an R script to populate two full columns (CIleft and CIright) with the confidence interval outputs using the CIr function within the "psychometric" package for each row of data. This CIr function operates as follows, outputting the left and right confidence interval values:

```
CIr(r = .9, n = 100, level = .95)  
[1] 0.8546667 0.9317133
```

Below is my unsuccessful script.

```
CI <- function(x)
{
  require(psychometric)
  library(psychometric)
  r <- x["dataset$exit"];
  n <- x["dataset$samplesize"];
  results <- CIr(r, n, level = .95);
  x["dataset$CIleft"] <- results[1];
  x["dataset$CIright"] <- results[2];
}
```

One complication (which I believe may be relevant) is that test runs of "CI(x)" in the console produce the following errors:

```
// Error in CIz(z, n, level) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Then entering `dataset2 <- as.matrix(dataset)` and trying `CI(x)` again yields:

```
Error in dataset2$exit : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

And for

```
dataset3 <- lapply(dataset$exit, as.numeric)
dataset4 <- lapply(dataset$samplesize, as.numeric)
```

trying `CI(x)` again yields:

```
Error in 1 + x : non-numeric argument to binary operator //
```

Can anyone assist in helping me populate each row of my data frame with the appropriate output for `CIleft` and `CIright`, given that `r = 'exit'`, and `n = 'samplesize'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a function.

```
library("psychometric")

dataset$lwr = NULL
dataset$upr = NULL

for (row in 1:nrow(dataset)){
   dataset[["lwr"]][row] <- CIr(r = dataset[["exit"]][row], n = dataset[["samplesize"]][row], level = .95)[1]
   dataset[["upr"]][row] <- CIr(r = dataset[["exit"]][row], n = dataset[["samplesize"]][row], level = .95)[2]
}
```

---

I will note though that it's generally advisable to avoid `for` loops in `R` because of its architecture (i.e., they're slow). Perhaps someone else can provide a solution with something else, e.g., `apply`. However, if you only have a small dataframe, the speed cost of using a `for` loop is unlikely to be noticeable.

---

Test Data:

```
set.seed(55); m = rnorm(26, 20, 40); dataset = data.frame( exit = seq(0, 1, 0.04), samplesize = abs(round(m)))
dataset$samplesize[dataset$samplesize == 0] = 5
dataset$exit[dataset$exit == 1] = 0.99
```

Comment: Worked great, InNoam. Thanks so much, I owe you one!

Comment: Happy to try and help. Cheers